# Error with OpenCV code - Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code, which runs fine:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void main() {

    bool running = true;

    cv::OrbFeatureDetector OrbDetector;

    while (running) {
        IplImage *newFrame = cvLoadImage("x1.jpg");
        IplImage *newFrameBW = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(newFrame), newFrame->depth, 1);
        cvConvertImage(newFrame, newFrameBW);
        vector<KeyPoint> KeyPoints;
    }
}
```

However, adding the line:

```
OrbDetector.detect(newFrameBW, KeyPoints);
```

to the while loop results in the following error:

```
HEAP[Example 4.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 006B0000, 02474D20 )
Example 4.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

I am sure there is nothing wrong with the code, as I have just seen it run successfully on someone elses machine. Is there anything non code related that could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the OpenCV version you are using does not deal OK with MCVS 2012. Is not a problem of code, as I had a similar one that include vectors and didn't work.
Take a look to this tutorial that will show you how to rebuild the OpenCV library and your code will work pretty well ;)
Here is the link:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/6495/visual-studio-2012-and-rtlfreeheap-error/